# C# Console Loop Proceed On KeyUp

Tags: c#, loops

I need to make it to where my code will only exit the loop when the key that is pressed, is released. I am doing this is console and will need to stay in console.

Here is an example of the code.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo = ki;

while (true)
{
    ki = Console.ReadKey();

    if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }
}
```

As you can see above, when the <kbd>A</kbd> key is pressed, it will write A in the console. If you hold down the <kbd>A</kbd> key, it will continuously write A.

What I'm wanting is for the console to write A **ONCE** until the A key is released. Then, if you press <kbd>A</kbd> again, it will print again.

I've thought about using "KeyUp" but I'm not able to use it on a console application. But something that would accomplish the following...

```
ConsoleKeyInfo = ki;

while (true)
{
    ki = Console.ReadKey();

    if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
    {
        //I know the following isn't actually code, but it's explaining what I want to happen.
        do (onKeyRelease)
        {
            Console.Write("A");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm wanting only one thing to happen when the loop when a key is pressed until the key is released. When the key is released, the loop will start again.

Please note that I am using this idea for a Text-Based RPG game. So waiting until another key is pressed (including adding another **Console.ReadKey()** to the end) would not be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

*1st Suggestion* - Have you tried "break" the loop when the console has displayed the "A"?

*2nd Suggestion* -

```
ConsoleKeyInfo = ki;
var alreadyPressed = false
while (true)
{
ki = Console.ReadKey();


if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.A && !alreadyPressed)
{        
        Console.Write("A");
        alreadyPressed = true;        
}}`
```

Comment: I'm wanting it to loop, though. If I break the loop, I will not be able to input anything else.

Comment: Yes, I have. Unfortunately it will do the exact same thing as my original code. Rather than creating a way to edit the loop, I'm wanting to only proceed when the key pressed is released. That way people cannot hold down the key.

Answer (score 0):

Store last pressed key and print character only when it is different from the last pressed key.

Comment: I'm using this for the controls to a Text-Based RPG game. I need to make it to where I am able to go in the same direction. I'm just trying to prevent the console from trying to catch up with the repeated key.